# Saving/writing swift structs as a file or binary format

Tags: swift, struct

I have a Swift struct of Int32, floats and data and I want to save this struct instance in a binary format - Can someone help me on how to write  or save file in the binary format?

```
struct Another {
    let imgCount: UInt32
    let resetFlag: UInt32
    let focalX: Float
    let focalY: Float
    let somedata: Data
}
```

Also the `MemoryLayout<Another>.size` and `MemoryLayout<Another>.stripe` is confusing.

Comment: Does it' require interop with other programs, perhaps on other platforms?

Comment: You want to save JSON as file then you can use library created by me https://github.com/PrashantKT/Swift4-Locally-save-JSON-

Comment: You should consider using Swift native types lik Int and Float .

Comment: @trojanfoe - Yes, I am trying to pass this struct to another javascript where the struct protocol would define the data for the js there.

Comment: @prashantTukadiya converting to JSON seems a long way around. I want to save the struct as raw binary

Comment: @JTea __uint32_t is alias of UInt32 and float_t is alias of Float. That shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: @AppuNewbie You do know what the "js" part of "json" means don't you?  If you are passing the data to javascript then why would you want to write it as binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to reserve the first 16 bytes (4 bytes for each numeric property  because they are all 32 bits). The tail of the data will be used for the data property `someData` which can be of any size:

```
struct Another {
    // UInt32 - A 32-bit unsigned integer value type. You will need 4 bytes for each property
    // 4 + 4 = 8 Bytes
    let imgCount, resetFlag: UInt32
    // Float - A single-precision, floating-point value type. Again 4 bytes for each property
    // 4 + 4 = 8 Bytes
    let focalX, focalY: Float
    // the data can have any size this will be all bytes from index 16 until the end of the file
    let someData: Data
}
```

To convert the numeric types to Data and back you can use the following helpers:

```
extension Numeric {
    var data: Data {
        var source = self
        return Data(bytes: &source, count: MemoryLayout<Self>.size)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    func object<T>() -> T { withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) } }
}
```

Now you just need to create a custom initializer to decode your data iterating over your data and set the correspond properties values.

```
extension Another {
    init(_ data: Data) {

        var startIndex = data.startIndex
        var endIndex = startIndex.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
        let imgCountRange = startIndex..<endIndex
        self.imgCount = data[imgCountRange].object()

        startIndex = endIndex
        endIndex = startIndex.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
        let resetFlagRange = startIndex..<endIndex
        self.resetFlag = data[resetFlagRange].object()

        startIndex = endIndex
        endIndex = startIndex.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
        let focalXRange = startIndex..<endIndex
        self.focalX = data[focalXRange].object()

        startIndex = endIndex
        endIndex = startIndex.advanced(by: MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
        let focalYRange = startIndex..<endIndex
        self.focalY = data[focalYRange].object()

        self.someData = data[endIndex...]
    }
}
```

---

To encode your structure will be much easier:

```
extension Another {
    var data: Data {
        return imgCount.data + resetFlag.data + focalX.data + focalY.data + someData
    }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let obj1 = Another(imgCount: 1, resetFlag: 2, focalX: 3.4, focalY: 5.6, someData: Data([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
let obj2 = Another(imgCount: 3, resetFlag: 4, focalX: 5.6, focalY: 7.8, someData: Data([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]))

let obj1Data = obj1.data
print(obj1Data)  // 27 bytes
let obj1FromData = Another(obj1Data)
print(obj1FromData)
let obj2Data = obj2.data
print(obj2Data)  // 29 bytes
let obj2FromData = Another(obj2Data)
print(obj2FromData)
```

This will print

> 27 bytes
>
> Another(imgCount: 1, resetFlag: 2, focalX: 3.4, focalY: 5.6,
> someData: 11 bytes)
>
> 29 bytes
>
> Another(imgCount: 3, resetFlag: 4,
> focalX: 5.6, focalY: 7.8, someData: 13 bytes)

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was looking for.